# Magento 2 - Form Validation

Tags: magento2, form-validation

is there a overview for the new form validation attributes in Magento 2?

Answer (score 51):

There are 3 different ways to use form validation in magento 2

To enable javascript validation use following code in your template

```
<form class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
 <fieldset class="fieldset">
     <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Personal Information') ?></span></legend><br>
      <div class="field required">
          <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
          <div class="control">
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email_address" value="" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
          </div>
      </div>
 </fieldset>
 <div class="actions-toolbar">
      <div class="primary">
          <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php  echo __('Submit') ?>"><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></button>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

1

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#custom-form": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

2

```
<form data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

   var dataForm = $('#custom-form');
   dataForm.mage('validation', {});

});
</script>
```

*custom-form is form id you can replace it with your form id

**List of form validation rules**

To wrap up this article, a list of validation rule names is provided here as a quick reference toward the official documentation:

**Magento rules:**

```
validate-no-html-tags

validate-select

validate-no-empty

validate-alphanum-with-spaces

validate-data

validate-street

validate-phoneStrict

validate-phoneLax

validate-fax

validate-email

validate-emailSender

validate-password

validate-admin-password

validate-customer-password

validate-url

validate-clean-url

validate-xml-identifier

validate-ssn

validate-zip-us

validate-date-au

validate-currency-dollar

validate-not-negative-number

validate-zero-or-greater

validate-greater-than-zero

validate-css-length

validate-number

required-number

validate-number-range

validate-digits

validate-digits-range

validate-range

validate-alpha

validate-code

validate-alphanum

validate-date

validate-date-range

validate-cpassword

validate-identifier

validate-zip-international

validate-one-required

validate-state

required-file

validate-ajax-error

validate-optional-datetime

validate-required-datetime

validate-one-required-by-name

less-than-equals-to

greater-than-equals-to

validate-emails

validate-cc-type-select

validate-cc-number

validate-cc-type

validate-cc-exp

validate-cc-cvn

validate-cc-ukss

validate-length

required-entry

not-negative-amount

validate-per-page-value-list

validate-per-page-value

validate-new-password

required-if-not-specified

required-if-all-sku-empty-and-file-not-loaded

required-if-specified

required-number-if-specified

datetime-validation

required-text-swatch-entry

required-visual-swatch-entry

required-dropdown-attribute-entry

Validate-item-quantity

validate-grouped-qty

validate-one-checkbox-required-by-name

validate-date-between

validate-dob

max-words

min-words

range-words

letters-with-basic-punc

alphanumeric

letters-only

no-whitespace

zip-range

integer

vinUS

dateITA

dateNL

time

time12h

phoneUS

phoneUK

mobileUK

stripped-min-length

email2

url2

credit-card-types

ipv4

ipv6

pattern

allow-container-className
```

**jQuery rules:**

```
required,

remote,

email,

url,

date,

dateISO,

number,

digits,

creditcard,

equalTo,

maxlength,

minlength,

rangelength,

range,

max,

min
```

refer http://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/

Comment: I want to apply server side validation in magento 2can you pls share me any link or doc,

Comment: I think you already asked question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161300/how-can-i-apply-server-side-validation-in-magento-2 May this link help other

Answer (score 42):

You can add class for validation in Magento 2. See example bellow. There is almost 72 rules (validation class) you can use:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'email_from',
    'text',
    ['name' => 'email_from', 'label' => __('Email From'), 'title' => __('Email From'), 'required' => true, 'class' => 'validate-email']
);
```

See [blog for list of available rules](http://blog.i13websolution.com/magento-2-validation-rules/) for more info:

> Here is list of validations classes rules supported by magento 2. You
>   just need to add css class for the rule to apply.
>
> ```
> min_text_length
> max_text_length
> max-words
> min-words
> range-words
> letters-with-basic-punc
> alphanumeric
> letters-only
> no-whitespace
> zip-range
> integer
> vinUS
> dateITA
> dateNL
> time
> time12h
> phoneUS
> phoneUK
> mobileUK
> stripped-min-length
> email2
> url2
> credit-card-types
> ipv4
> ipv6
> pattern
> validate-no-html-tags
> validate-select
> validate-no-empty
> validate-alphanum-with-spaces
> validate-data
> validate-street
> validate-phoneStrict
> validate-phoneLax
> validate-fax
> validate-email
> validate-emailSender
> validate-password
> validate-admin-password
> validate-url
> validate-clean-url
> validate-xml-identifier
> validate-ssn
> validate-zip-us
> validate-date-au
> validate-currency-dollar
> validate-not-negative-number
> validate-zero-or-greater
> validate-greater-than-zero
> validate-css-length
> validate-number
> validate-number-range
> validate-digits
> validate-digits-range
> validate-range
> validate-alpha
> validate-code
> validate-alphanum
> validate-date
> validate-identifier
> validate-zip-international
> validate-state
> less-than-equals-to
> greater-than-equals-to
> validate-emails
> validate-cc-number
> validate-cc-ukss
> required-entry
> checked
> not-negative-amount
> validate-per-page-value-list
> validate-new-password
> validate-item-quantity
> equalTo
> ```

Comment: is there any example how to use pattern? tnx

Answer (score 15):

In UI components it can be used by following sample config (Magento v2.2.0):

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="priority" sortOrder="1000" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="not-negative-amount" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                [...]
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

See more examples in file:
`vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml`

The validators list in UI Components it can be found in 
`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`.

Just wrote this script to grab all keys with error messages for explanation:

- **required-entry:**
  This is a required field.
- **validate-alphanum-with-spaces:**
  Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or spaces only in this field.
- **phoneUK:**
  Please specify a valid phone number
- **validate-email:**
  Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).
- **ipv4:**
  Please enter a valid IP v4 address.
- **checked:**
  This is a required field.
- **validate-select:**
  Please select an option.
- **ipv6:**
  Please enter a valid IP v6 address.
- **time:**
  Please enter a valid time, between 00:00 and 23:59
- **validate-number:**
  Please enter a valid number in this field.
- **validate-phoneLax:**
  Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.
- **dateITA:**
  Please enter a correct date
- **validate-xml-identifier:**
  Please enter a valid XML-identifier (Ex: something_1, block5, id-4).
- **validate-clean-url:**
  Please enter a valid URL. For example http://www.example.com or www.example.com.
- **validate-admin-password:**
  Please enter 7 or more characters, using both numeric and alphabetic.
- **validate-no-html-tags:**
  HTML tags are not allowed.
- **validate-integer:**
  Please enter a valid integer in this field.
- **validate-data:**
  Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore (_) in this field, and the first character should be a letter.
- **validate-cc-ukss:**
  Please enter issue number or start date for switch/solo card type.
- **min-words:**
  Please enter at least {0} words.
- **alphanumeric:**
  Letters, numbers, spaces or underscores only please
- **validate-identifier:**
  Please enter a valid URL Key (Ex: "example-page", "example-page.html" or "anotherlevel/example-page").
- **validate-street:**
  Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces and "#" in this field.
- **validate-zip-international:**
  Please enter a valid zip code.
- **validate-date:**
  Please enter a valid date.
- **validate-greater-than-zero:**
  Please enter a number greater than 0 in this field.
- **validate-digits:**
  Please enter a valid number in this field.
- **validate-ssn:**
  Please enter a valid social security number (Ex: 123-45-6789).
- **not-negative-amount:**
  Please enter positive number in this field.
- **validate-max-size:**
  File you are trying to upload exceeds maximum file size limit.
- **validate-fax:**
  Please enter a valid fax number (Ex: 123-456-7890).
- **validate-if-tag-script-exist:**
  Please use tag SCRIPT with SRC attribute or with proper content to include JavaScript to the document.
- **min_text_length:**
  Please enter more or equal than {0} symbols.
- **validate-date-au:**
  Please use this date format: dd/mm/yyyy. For example 17/03/2006 for the 17th of March, 2006.
- **mobileUK:**
  Please specify a valid mobile number
- **letters-with-basic-punc:**
  Letters or punctuation only please
- **validate-number-range:**
  The value is not within the specified range.
- **phoneUS:**
  Please specify a valid phone number
- **date_range_max:**
  The date is not within the specified range.
- **validate-range:**
  The value is not within the specified range.
- **vinUS:**
  The specified vehicle identification number (VIN) is invalid.
- **range-words:**
  Please enter between {0} and {1} words.
- **validate-zip-us:**
  Please enter a valid zip code (Ex: 90602 or 90602-1234).
- **validate-emails:**
  Please enter valid email addresses, separated by commas. For example, johndoe@domain.com, johnsmith@domain.com.
- **validate-css-length:**
  Please input a valid CSS-length (Ex: 100px, 77pt, 20em, .5ex or 50%).
- **zip-range:**
  Your ZIP-code must be in the range 902xx-xxxx to 905-xx-xxxx
- **validate-phoneStrict:**
  Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.
- **dateNL:**
  Vul hier een geldige datum in.
- **letters-only:**
  Letters only please
- **max_text_length:**
  Please enter less or equal than {0} symbols.
- **validate-not-negative-number:**
  Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.
- **validate-per-page-value-list:**
  Please enter a valid value, ex: 10,20,30
- **no-whitespace:**
  No white space please
- **validate-state:**
  Please select State/Province.
- **validate-url:**
  Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://).
- **date_range_min:**
  The date is not within the specified range.
- **validate-digits-range:**
  The value is not within the specified range.
- **greater-than-equals-to:**
  Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.
- **validate-no-empty:**
  Empty Value.
- **validate-zero-or-greater:**
  Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.
- **validate-cc-number:**
  Please enter a valid credit card number.
- **validate-emailSender:**
  Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).
- **validate-new-password:**
  Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.
- **validate-customer-password:**
  Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.
- **validate-password:**
  Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.
- **less-than-equals-to:**
  Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}.
- **validate-currency-dollar:**
  Please enter a valid $ amount. For example $100.00.
- **time12h:**
  Please enter a valid time, between 00:00 am and 12:00 pm
- **validate-alphanum:**
  Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) in this field. No spaces or other characters are allowed.
- **validate-item-quantity:**
  We don\'t recognize or support this file extension type.
- **validate-code:**
  Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore (_) in this field, and the first character should be a letter.
- **email2:**
  Please enter a valid credit card number.
- **max-words:**
  Please enter {0} words or less.
- **stripped-min-length:**
  Please enter at least {0} characters
- **validate-alpha:**
  Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.
- **pattern:**
  Invalid format.
- **integer:**
  A positive or negative non-decimal number please

The script:

```
declare -A list
key=''
while IFS= read -r line; do
#  echo "${line} -"
  if [ -z "${key:-}" ]; then
    # match validation key
    match=$(echo "${line}" | grep -Eo "^        ['\"]([A-Za-z0-9-]|_)+" | tr -d "' ")
    if [ -n "${match}" ]; then
      key=${match}
    fi
  else
    # match message
    match=$(echo "${line}" | sed -rn "s|.*\\$\.mage\.__[(]['\"](.*)['\"][)].*|\1|p")
    if [ -n "${match}" ]; then
      list[${key}]=${match}
      key=''
    fi
  fi
done < "${DOCROOT_DIR:-/var/www/html}/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js"

for i in "${!list[@]}"
do
  printf "%s:\n    %s\n" "${i}" "${list[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: How can i use it in my custom form? If i use like this <input type="text" name="primary_contact" data-validate="{'validate-phoneStrict':true}" class="valid"> it not working.

Answer (score 4):

When use **UI components** to make form, we could use the validation like below, it works in Magento 2.1.x, I doesn't test it in other version yet.

```
<field name="priority">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Priority</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module_name</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">priority</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validate-integer" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Notice the **validation** item, in it we could add **validation rules**, like `required-entry`, `validate-integer` etc.

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     <item name="validate-integer" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     <item name="validation_rule_name" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     ...
</item>
```

All validation rules you could find in file `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`, like `validate-date`, `validate-emails` etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you take reference of /customer/account/create page, you can see the following piece of code underneath the form:

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = null;

    dataForm.mage('validation', {
            ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
        }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

});
</script>
```

And if you check at form's input attributes, you can see Magento 1 like `class` attribute values along with new `data-validate` attribute.
This can be the basis to step up.

Keys files for Validation:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/develop/lib/web/jquery/jquery.validate.js
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/develop/lib/web/mage/validation.js
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/develop/lib/web/mage/validation/validation.js

Comment: Thx for the answer. I found the new attribute data-validate too, but it's interesting what validations are available. In my case I want to validate a Checkbox and a set of RadioButton

Comment: I want to apply server side validation in magento 2 can you pls share me any link or doc.

Answer (score 1):

I have same requirement for Magento2 Form Validation and i did this code

**First we will setup a test form**

```
<!-- form tag -->
<form class="form" id="custom-form-id" method="post" autocomplete="off">
   <fieldset class="fieldset">
       <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('User Personal Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <!-- form field -->
            <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email_address" value="" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
   </fieldset>
   <!-- submit button -->
   <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php  echo __('Submit') ?>"><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**To enable javascript validation for Magento2 Form Validation**

```
<!-- enable javascript validation for custom-form-id -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#custom-form-id": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

**[Reference](http://www.onlinecode.org/magento2-form-validation-example/)** :: http://www.onlinecode.org/magento2-form-validation-example/

Answer (score 0):

"no-whitespace" option does not work correctly (at least on Magento 2.1). It triggers an error message on any type of "space" character.
Values "test me" and "  test me   " will return the same error.