# uiForm validation?

Tags: magento2, form-validation, uicomponent, ui-form

I found this list validation rules:

> [Magento 2 - Form Validation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95171/magento-2-form-validation)

How to use above list of validation rules in **uiForm-uiComponent**. Can I add it inside **xml** `<field>` tag? or at least how to set required fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple xml code for **field required**

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

**date validation**

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

**validate-email**

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

for example look at

**vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml**