# How Can I apply server side validation in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.3, validation, form-validation

I am new to magento 2, and I want to apply server side validations, Can anyone please help me, Or suggest me how to apply. I have searched many links for this but i didnot understand.
Here is my phtml file (request.phtml)

```
<div class="wk-mp-design">
    <fieldset class="fieldset info wk-mp-fieldset">
        <legend class="legend">
            <span><?php echo __('Quote Request') ?></span>
        </legend>
  <form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('quote/contact/save', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]) ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="quote-request" data-form="quote-request" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Full Name') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" title="Full Name" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Street Address') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="street_address" name="street_address" title="Street Address" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Suburb') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="district" name="district" title="Suburb" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Post Code') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="post_code" name="post_code" title="Post Code" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"  />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Phone Number') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" title="Phone Number" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Email Address') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" title="Email Address" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <?php echo __("Please attach any photo's that will help describe your job.(Max 5 images/3Mb of data. JPGS Only)") ?>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment"  title="Attachment" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
              <button class="button wk-mp-btn" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" type="submit" id="submit-btn">
                <span><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></span>
            </button>
              <button class="button wk-mp-btn" title="<?php echo __('Reset') ?>" >
                <span><span><?php echo __('Reset') ?></span></span>
            </button>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#quote-request": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have applied client side validations, but I am not getting how to apply server side validations.

Answer (score 6):

You can use server side validation as below:

```
if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
      $error = true;
}
if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
      $error = true;
}
if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
      $error = true;
 }
 if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
      $error = true;
 }
```

For more information you can check below contact post controller code:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Contact\Controller\Index;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index
{
    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact/index');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact/index');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not log Exception in order to have exception stack trace ?