# I want to add jquery validation to my form ! How can i do it?

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, css, requirejs, luma-theme

I am using magento's inbuilt luma theme to practise and  i am not able to understand where exactly is js written how is the flow ?

This is my basic view page. And is working fine i want to add jquery validation here.

```
<!---- Form  --->
<div class="container">
  <h2>Add Content</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Name</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Post Content</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<!--------------------->
```

Comment: Sorry the form just did'nt get uploaded here , i strictly want add jquery validation where can i write ?? How is the flow pleae help !!

Comment: The form is now displaying for you ;)

Comment: Yeah ... :) I want to add jquery validation to it .. where should i place the code ?

Comment: I haven't worked with validation on M2 yet so I can't answer sorry, this answer should help though - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95171/magento-2-form-validation

Answer (score 0):

Please change your form tag with the below code and then check.

```
<form class="form contact"
  action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
  id="contact-form"
  method="post"
  data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
```

Comment: I have a quik question what to write inside data-mage-init = '{ " validation" :{           ????????????        }}'>

Comment: that was syntax for validation. nothing to write between that.