# How to add phone mask to checkout page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I need to add a mask to telephone on a checkout page, like +9-(999)-999-99-99.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95171/magento-2-form-validation

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at at this [jQuery Mask plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)? Include the script in the head of your website and then call the following below the input field:

```
$('#billing:telephone').mask('+0-(000)-000-00-00');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it help you.. 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_zip.html

> Please edit in these file in your module

Add the following in `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`

**example:**   `magento2root/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="customValidate" xsi:type="string">true</item>
  </item>
</item>
```

**Add custom validation as per your need in**

> vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\mage\validation.js

```
"customValidate": [
    function (phone_number, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/([+]?\d{1,2}[.-\s]?)?(\d{3}[.-]?){2}\d{4}/g) &&
        phone_number.match(/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/);
    },
        'Please specify a valid mobile number with country code example +9-(999)-999-99-99'
  ],
```

**Add following in**

> vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\lib\validation\rules.js

```
"customValidate": [
            function(value) {
                return value.length > 9 && value.match(/([+]?\d{1,2}[.-\s]?)?(\d{3}[.-]?){2}\d{4}/g) && value.match(/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please specify a valid mobile number')
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If by mask you mean format it like that

so change 99999999999 to +9-(999)-999-99-99

then you could write a simple php format function something like:

```
$data = '+11234567890';

if(  preg_match( '/^\+\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $data,  $matches ) )
{
    $result = $matches[1] . '-' .$matches[2] . '-' . $matches[3];
    return $result;
}
```

and then change the pattern to your liking