# Magento 2 remove class required in edit.phtml

Tags: magento2, forms

I have problem with postcode field in magento 2. Somewhere magento remove class required from

```
<div class="field zip required test">
        <label class="label" for="zip"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
```

When i added class 'test' i see this, but required is removed somewhere. Do you have any hint? In database I update eav_attribute postcode (I set is_required= 1)

edit: I find solution. Problem was in getCountriesWithOptionalZip(). Now zip code is required, but not validate postcode by country. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set postcode field required then you have to add `data-validate="{required:true}"`  in input .

Your final html will be

```
<input type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>">
```

Magento 2 does not validate input field the way it used to do in Magento 1 by adding class.

Comment: I added data-validate, but still magento remove class from div. Additional not work validate zip code by country.

Comment: just add data-validate you don't need to add class

Comment: check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149857/20064