# JS VarienForm in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, validation

Is there a way to update this code to work with Magento2? I believe VarienForm has been depreciated in Magento2 but I can't find a similar JS constructor to get the object.

```
var AddToCartForm = new VarienForm('#my_form');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VarienForm has been depreciated in Magento2.

You can try it;

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

   var dataForm = $('#my_form');
   dataForm.mage('validation', {});

});
</script>
```

For details, you can look at this answer.

[Magento 2 - Form Validation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149857/78243)

Comment: Does this turn the form into an object for further manipulation the way VarienForm does?