# Form validation is not working in my custom form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, jquery, magento2.4.2

```
<div id="popup-modal"> 
<div class="contact-form-popup" style="display:none;">

    <form class="form contact"
          action="<?= $block->getUrl("popup/action/index") ?>"
          id="contact-form"
          method="post"
          data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get in touch')) ?></span></legend>
            <br/>
            <div class="field note no-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Simply fill in your details and enquiry below and one of our team will be in touch as soon as possible.')) ?></div>
            <div class="field firstname required">
                <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Name')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field emailaddress required">
                <label class="label" for="emailaddress"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer email address')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field mobile">
                <label class="label" for="mobile"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone number')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="mobile" id="mobile" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone number')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field postcode">
                <label class="label" for="postcode"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer postcode')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="postcode" id="postcode" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Customer postcode')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field enquiry required">
                <label class="label" for="enquiry"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Enquiry')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Enquiry')) ?>"
                        class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field extension required">
                <input type='hidden' name="extension" id="extension-name"
                       class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" id='customer-contact' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>"
                        class="action submit primary">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="static-block-message">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get in touch')) ?></span></legend>
            <br/>
    <div class="field note no-label">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Simply fill in your details and enquiry below and one of our team will be in touch as soon as possible.')) ?>
    </div>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Thanku you.A member of our team will be in touch shortly.'))?>
    <div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function($, modal) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                
                buttons: []
            };
            var openModal = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

            jQuery('body').on('click', '.demo-banner .pagebuilder-button-primary', function(){
                jQuery('.contact-form-popup').show();
                jQuery('.static-block-message').hide();
                jQuery('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            });

            jQuery('body').on('click', '#contact-form .action.submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl("popup/action/index") ?>',
                    data: jQuery('#contact-form').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    showLoader: 'true',
                    success: function(response) {
                        //alert('success');
                        jQuery('.contact-form-popup').hide();
                        jQuery('.static-block-message').show();
                        
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

This is my phtml code.

Here, when I am submitting the form with empty fields, form validation is not triggering. It is submitting with empty fields only. How can i trigger form validation in my phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

At then end of your .phtml file, add this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage',
        'mage/validation'
    ], function($){
        var contact_form = jQuery('#contact-form');
        contact_form.mage('validation', {});
    });
</script>
```

Another thing, you have missed formKey part in your form
so add this line in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>"/>
```

This will initiate validation on your from.
Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi @Shoaib i try this but it not working, could you pls tell me is there any worng in my phtml file

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form" id="contact-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
 <fieldset class="fieldset">
     <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get in touch')) ?></span></legend>
            <br/>
      <div class="field required">

          <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Name')) ?></span></label>
              
          <div class="control">
              <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>                           
          </div>
      </div>
 </fieldset>
 <div class="actions-toolbar">
      <div class="primary">
          <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php  echo __('Submit') ?>"><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></button>
      </div>
  </div>

 .....
 .....
</form>
```

Add javascript

```
 <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#contact-form": {
                "validation": {}
            }
        }
    </script>
```

You can get addditional details from

[Magento 2 - Form Validation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95171/magento-2-form-validation)

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/